# Android java.io.FileNotFoundException with Jpg

Tags: java, android, exception

I have to draw an image located on asstes/images on a ImageView.
First of all I save all the files in the assets/images folder on a String array.

```
try {
        String [] immages = assetManager.list("images");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And with Log.d I can see that all the images are scanned correctly.
Then I have this method that returns a Bitmap that will be set on a ImageView

```
private Bitmap readImg()
{
    InputStream inputStreamImages = null;
    Resources res = getResources();
    Bitmap bmp= null;
    try {

        inputStreamImages = assetManager.open(images[Integer.parseInt(number) - 1]);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStreamImages);
        } catch(IOException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
    return bmp;
}
```

But I made another method because that one didn't worked.

```
private Drawable readImg2()
{
    Drawable d= null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStreamImages = getAssets().open(images[Integer.parseInt(number) - 1]);
        d = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStreamImages, null);
        }catch(IOException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
    return d;
}
```

The are very similar but both throw the same Error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: v2.jpg

Can anyone help me? Thank you ;D

Comment: Can you print out the path to the image in both cases?

Comment: It should look something like `file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_234234.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`images` Array contains only image names with extension instead of image names with directory in which files are available so add `images` as prefix when passing to `assetManager.open` method as :

```
    InputStream inputStreamImages = 
                assetManager.open("images/"+images[Integer.parseInt(number) - 1]);
```

Comment: It works! Problem solved, i didn't think of a mistake on the images array. Thank you!